# Why is app undefined when called from controller?

Tags: php, lumen

I wonder why I can't access `$app` from my controllers.

I'm using this service provider that I register in `app.php`.

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
```

The documentations tells me to use it as follows (from a controller):

```
$pdf = $app->make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();
```

or:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();
```

Either way gives me the following error

```
Undefined variable: app
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Any pointers?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lumen you should use the `app()` helper method (see [Lumen docs](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/container)) to get an instance of a class.

Here is an example, that I used.

`routes/web.php`

```php
<?php

/** @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */

$router->get('/', 'ExampleController@index');
```

`app/Http/Controllers/ExampleController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        /** @var Dompdf $pdf */
        $pdf = app('dompdf');
        $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');

        // Output whatever you like
        return $pdf->outputHtml();
    }
}
```